# I want my Python script to detect the version and quit gracefully in case of a mismatch

Tags: python, version

I'd like to make it as general as possible - e.g. handle as many versions as possible.

Since version 3 is not backwards compatible with version 2, I want to make sure that I use the right print statement.

Please let me know if you have questions and feel free to share related knowledge having to do with dynamic logic based on what (e.g. libraries) is available.

Suppose I have a script that will run under version 1.x, or 2.x, or 3.x only.

Or a script which requires a library A or a library B.

Thanks!

***EDIT:***

Now ... when it comes to Python (unlike .Net) some libraries like SciPy, Google App Engine keep you glued to particular version. On Linux, Mac Os you can switch between different Python installs on command line. This is why I want to avoid confusion - I want to remember which script is for which version of Python and what libraries it needs. I would rather have it fail in a human-readable way.

Comment: Please do not mix syntax between Python 2 and Python 3.  Please do not.  There's a 2to3 tool that will rewrite your proper Python 2 into Python 3.  You maintain the Python 2 version, and you use the tool to create the Python 3 version.  This tool guarantees that you don't have any confusion.  You maintain Python 2 and convert cleanly to Python 3 with no confusion.

Comment: @S.Lott although "proper" Python 2 seems to mean writing some things for Python 2.6-only syntax, meaning you have to give up support for 2.5 and below. In particular, using `bytes()` and `b''` to indicate byte strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <s>If you want to maintain a codebase that works with Python 2 and 3, you wouldn't try to make code that will run in both, which will be awkward and ugly and bugprone, you would write in Python 2 and use `2to3` to convert. (You can also write in Python 3 and use `3to2` to convert, but I believe that tool is less mature.) `2to3` is not perfect, but making Python 2 code that can be converted by it makes tons more sense than making Python 2 code that will run in a Python 3 interpretter.</s> **Edit: This was common wisdom in 2010, but turned out not to be the case. The thing to do is write a polyglot. 2to3 did not end up being all that useful**
- Another option is [Cython](http://www.cython.org/), a Python-like language that can be used to create C extension modules. Cython modules can be used with Python 2 and 3.
- When you support multiple versions of Python, it is generally better to directly check for the capability you want rather than to check a version number. Checking version numbers directly is fragile and indirect.

  For example, if I wanted code that would work with Python pre-2.5, I would say:

  ```
  try: 
      any
  except NameError:
      def any(iterable):
          for item in iterable:
              if item:
                  return True
          return False
  ```

  (note that this is prettymuch the only reason to catch `NameError`). Similarly, library availability would be checked by catching `ImportError`. **Edit: There is a tons of tooling for abstracting this away by now.**
- If you want a script to remember what version it is from, like you say, don't bother trying to support multiple versions at all. Put the proper version number binary in the shebang line and run the script based on that.

Comment: +1: Use 2to3, that's what it's for.  Write Python 2 that converts properly and don't try to mix syntax.

Comment: In 2015, a large number of modules are written with Python 2 and 3 compatible code using libraries like [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) to make the process more simple.

Answer (score 9):

The `sys` module also contains the version info (first available in version 2.0):

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    print("You are using Python 2.x")
elif sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    print("You are using Python 3.x")
```

Comment: This is **useless** if the code contains a syntax that is considered an error in one PY version but not in another! In which case, the compiler will stop and the above code will never be executed! It is very interesting that the owner of the answer, its editor, all the upvoters and probably most readers missed this!! (This is a classic case for downvoting, which I never do. I prefer indicating mistakes than "punishing" them.)

Answer (score 8):

In order to get around syntax errors you would have to use conditional imports, if you want to mix syntax between versions 2 and 3.

```
# just psuedocode
if version is x:
   import lib_x # contains version x implementation
else:
   import lib_y # contains version y compatible implementation
```

It is not advisable to try to maintain compatibility between python3 and older versions. That said, here are several ways of detecting the version of python being used:

While not particularly human friendly, `sys.hexversion` will work across the widest variety of python versions, since it was added back in version 1.5.2:

```
import sys
if sys.hexversion == 0x20505f0:
    print "It's version 2.5.5!"
```

You should be able to get version information from `sys.version_info` (added in python 2.0):

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    print "You are using version 2!"
else:
    print "You are using version 1, because you would get SyntaxErrors if you were using 3!"
```

Alternatively you could use the platform module, though that was introduced in python 2.3, and  would not be available in older versions (assuming you even care about them):

```
try:
    import platform
    if platform.python_version().startswith('2'):
        print "You're using python 2.x!"
except ImportError, e:
    print "You're using something older than 2.3. Yuck."
```

Comment: I suppose it is as simple as this. Of course it must be either print or print(). Thanks!

Comment: sys.version_info is a tuple containing the version X.Y.Z not a function.

Comment: Just in case, I do care about older versions. By the way, your second edit will not work on Python 3.x :(

Comment: The second edit will not work in any Python version. sys.version_info has always been a tuple and not a function. His code is just wrong.

Comment: Since which version is this available?

Comment: First available in version 2.0.

Comment: Please do not mix Python 2 and 3.  Please use the 2to3 tool and do it properly.

Answer (score 3):

If the only issue is that you want to use the right print statement to avoid syntax errors, you can avoid the problem altogether by using the `print()` function in Python 2.6:

```
if sys.version_info[0:2] == (2,6):           # Or you could use try/except here
    from __future__ import print_function
print("Now you can use print as a function regardless of whether you're on 2.6 or 3.x!")
```

Of course, if you also want to support earlier versions of Python, this won't work.

Comment: I want to do a number of things. This is food for thought. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you want an *unconditional* `from __future__ import print_function` here. That version would still work fine on 2.6, but it wouldn't break with 2.7 like yours does. (This is what I mean when I say trying to handle different versions by checking the version information is fragile.)

Answer (score 2):

FYI, if you ever want to port 2.x scripts to 3.x, you can use [2to3 source conversion tool](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html).

Comment: @hamish : not exactly... but it automates most of the process... see: http://www.diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: Yes.  It's "spotless".  If you write your Python 2 correctly (which is very easy to do) The 2to3 tool will convert to Python 3 and you do not have any confusion or any thinking or any maintenance.  It is the best way to have code that runs in both environments.  You write (and maintain) Python 2 and use the 2to3 tool to create your Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, Mac etc, you should use the standard first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

On Windows, having such a first line is useful from a documentation point of view, even if Windows doesn't use it to choose the interpreter.